# Invalid Method Declaration: Return type missing

Tags: java

Ok so I updated the code and now it compiles. But when I run this, it does not have the window pop up with the Shape Stamper. I do not know why it it not coming up. 
Is it because I have a line that says: `public void StamperFrame()`?

I tried removing the void and it gives an error when I do that. It says invalid method declaration: Return type missing. The code still compiles and says successful, but it will not.

Here is the code now:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class ShapeStamper extends JFrame {

        public static void main(String[] args){
   ShapeStamper s = new ShapeStamper();
        s.StamperFrame();
}
        private JButton circleButton, squareButton, rectButton,ovalButton;
        private int buttonValue = 0;

        public void StamperFrame() {
            setTitle("Shape Stamper");
            setSize(500, 500);

            JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

            circleButton = new JButton("Circle");
            ovalButton = new JButton("Oval");
            squareButton = new JButton("Square");
            rectButton = new JButton("Rectangle");

            buttonPanel.add(circleButton);
            buttonPanel.add(squareButton);
            buttonPanel.add(rectButton);
            buttonPanel.add(ovalButton);
            getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            circleButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    buttonValue = 1;
                    System.out.println(buttonValue);
                }
            });
            ovalButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    buttonValue = 2;
                    System.out.println(buttonValue);
                }
            });
            squareButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    buttonValue = 3;
                    System.out.println(buttonValue);
                }
            });
            rectButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    buttonValue = 4;
                    System.out.println(buttonValue);
                }
            });

            getContentPane().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (buttonValue == 1) {
                        System.out.println("Circle added at: " + e.getX() + ","     + e.getY());
                    } else if (buttonValue == 2) {
                        System.out.println("Oval added at: " + e.getX() + "," +     e.getY());
                    } else if (buttonValue == 3) {
                        System.out.println("Square added at: " + e.getX() + ","     + e.getY());
                    } else if (buttonValue == 4) {
                        System.out.println("Rectangle added at: " + e.getX() +       "," + e.getY());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Methods can't contain fields or methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class ShapeStamper extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        StamperFrame(); //Add this line
}
```

AND don't forget the return value of stamperframe method

public **VOID** StamperFrame(){…}

EDIT Try this

```
public class ShapeStamper extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args){
         ShapeStamper s = new ShapeStamper(); //Add this line
         s.StamperFrame(); //Add this line
}
```

EDIT you should make the frame visible

```
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
this.setResizable(false);

this.setSize(500, 500);
this.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: i did that, now its giving me a different error.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - non-static method StamperFrame() cannot be referenced from a static context
 at ShapeStamper.main(ShapeStamper.java:19)
Java Result: 1

Comment: see my update. You cannot invoke a non static method from a static one… that's why the class is instantiated… so the method StamperFrame can be called on it

Comment: ok i did that, but now the java window i need to pop up so i can actually draw the shapes is not coming up. Any idea on why that is not happening? The code is compiling with no issues. I updated the main body of the question with my new code

Comment: you need to set your window to be visible call `setVisible(true)` inside your `StamperFrame()`

Comment: It comes up now. Thank You